# .gitignore in XCode5 doesn't seem to ignore files

Tags: git, version-control, xcode5

I have a .gitignore file in my app's root directory; no matter where I place it, Git seems to ignore the contents, such as xcuserstate.  This is the contents of my .gitignore file:

```
# Xcode
#
build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcuserstate
DBChooser.*
```

This is partially what shows when I do a *commit* from XCode5's Source Control menu item:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that the files you're trying to ignore are already under version control. You need to remove them from version control by running `git rm --cached <file>` on all those files, then make a commit. After that, what's listed in `.gitignore` should be properly ignored.

Comment: Thank you... I'll fix it this morning... SD